# How to typehint package class objects in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, static-typing

I'm digging into type hinting in Python and everything is clear when we talking about typehinting of built-in objects. But I don't understand what should be type hint for objects from some package. For example, here is my code with falcon web-framework:

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):
```

When I use type function on variables req and resp, I get "class 'falcon.request.Request' and "class 'falcon.response.Response'" respectively, so what should be the type hints for this variables, something like:

```
def on_post(self, req: 'falcon.request.Request', resp: 'falcon.response.Response') -> None:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes themselves as types:

```
from falcon.request import Request
from falcon.response import Response

# ...

def on_post(self, req: Request, resp: Response) -> None:
    # ...
```